# Add new device to exiting wildcard provisioning profile

Tags: ios-provisioning

I am trying to add a couple of new devices to our team provisioning profile. I am talking about the generic "wildcard" profile that we use to test apps before creating a specific profile for each of them.

As far as I recall, so far, any new device was automatically added to my team provisioning profile. The latest 2 device that I added today are not listed as part of the team profile. They are the only 2 device with a "0" count in the profile column. 
Also, the team profile is not editable, since it uses the wildcard.

Shouldn't the team profile include, by definition, all device? Is this a bug on the dev portal? Do you have any suggestion?

Cheers,
Davide

Comment: I'm facing similar kind of issue. Those 2 devices which are mentioned, have been added to your device list?

Comment: In my case, using wild card profile, I am able to install my app to any device, even when its newly bought. Strange for me?

Comment: Did you manage to add the devices? I am also experiencing this issue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in a comment, the only reliable solution is actually creating an app-specific profile.
It's more of a workaround really, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the iOS Team Provisioning Profile is generated and managed by Xcode.

If you add the device in the Provisioning Portal, then hit refresh in the Xcode organiser window (bottom right when looking at Library->Provisioning Profiles in Xcode 4), the profile should be regenerated and downloaded.

Comment: It is, but the devices are still not added to it.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I am using Xcode 7 now, I used Xcode 6 to refresh the profile.

I go to Xcode > Preferences > Account
[image: Preferences]
[image: Accounts]

I select the account and press View Details
[image: View Details]

I select the wildcard provisioning profile and press the refresh button
[image: wildcard profile]
[image]

After that, I go to member developer center to verify that the new device I added is included in the wildcard provisioning profile. Confirmed this will work.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32574260/1635363

Answer (score 0):

Did you recreate/download the provisioning profile after adding the new devices?

Comment: I did redownload the profile, but how am I supposed to recreate it? I tried to refresh via xcode, but I saw no changes. On the developer portal the 2 new devices have still a "0" in their profile count, while all other have at least a "1".

Comment: I think you need to go into the provisioning profile on the developer portal site and resave it.  Then download the latest copy.

Comment: Tried that. Unluckily the team profile cannot be modified/saved. It's the one profile that has no "edit" button on the list. It's always updated itself automatically, except this time.

Comment: We generally use app-specific profiles with the full bundle name specified, this has worked better for us than trying to wildcard.  When you get into things like push notifications you will need a separate certificate anyhow.  This also allows the "iPhone Developer" profile to auto-select the appropriate one, resulting in fewer project file conflicts.
 ... 
If you are set on wildcarding, you could create a com.companyname.* profile and use it instead.  Sorry, I'm not too familiar with the generic wildcard profile - but I would think that it should auto-update as devices are added.