# Xcode 7 no longer has a profile refresh button - so how to add new device ids to a profile?

Tags: xcode

I've just added a new device to the provisioning portal. Previously the next step would then be to manually update the relevant profiles to add this new device, however it seems this is now handled automatically by Xcode and its no longer possible to edit the profiles via the provisioning portal to include the new device. (There is no longer an edit button in the portal).

Ok, however the latest version of Xcode (Xcode 7 GM Seed) no longer has a refresh button to update the profiles so how are you now supposed to refresh/update profiles when a new device gets added to include that new device in the profile?

Comment: I had the same issue, glad you brought it up on SO, I basically had to open Xcode 6 and do a refresh. I hope there is a much better solution for this.

Comment: There's also no way to refresh the profiles with Xcode 7.1 beta either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> however it seems this is now handled automatically by Xcode and its no longer possible to edit the profiles via the provisioning portal to include the new device

Your premise is false: there *is* an edit button in the portal for provisioning profiles, *if* this is a profile that you (not Xcode) created:

[image]

So, as you can see, for an ad hoc profile, you can edit and add the device manually.

If all you're trying to do is run on a device directly from Xcode, just run! If there's a problem, Xcode will regenerate the wildcard development profile for you automatically.

Answer (score 5):

Xcode 6 had a circular arrow refresh profiles button, with Xcode 7 this has been replaced with a download profiles button. However this download button doesn't do anything in terms of updating the profiles. I tested this by:

```
a) Examining the profiles in the portal. They say there are N devices enabled by the profile.
b) Add a new device id to the portal. The profiles still say they enable N devices.
c) From within Xcode 7 click the download profiles button.
d) The profiles in the portal still say there are N devices enabled.
e) From within Xcode 6.4, click the refresh profiles button. It spins and does something.
f) Now the profiles say there are N + 1 devices enabled.
```

So until some other workaround is found, or there's a new feature in Xcode 7 that isn't common knowledge tribal knowledge yet, or its a bug in Xcode 7 and apple fix it, at the moment the only known way to update any changes to profiles is to switch back to Xcode 6.4 and refresh them from there.

Comment: OK, just verified this does work in Xcode 6 and I found no equivalent in Xcode 7.  This is very puzzling.  It makes me think that Apple killed this to break beta distributions through third party apps like Hockey App.

Comment: Thanks. Now 1 new device is added to the wildcard when I clicked refresh on Xcode 6.1.1. Better not delete Xcode 6 version first. Thanks again. :) @Sausage Modulation Matrix